# Не работает селектор siblings Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Возникла проблема с селекторами.

Смотрел [документацию](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5), вроде все делаю правильно, но ни черта не работает.

Я хочу сделать удаление содержания формы регистрации при нажатии на крестик, а скрипт сделать универсальный, при нажатии на элемент с классом крестик (их много, у каждого input - свой) скрипт должен найти "соседа" с классом form_control и очистить его. Но при нажатии ничего не происходит.

Код ниже:
index.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Введите ваш login:</label>
  <input id='loginLog' class="form_control logins" type="text" placeholder="login" value="">
  <img src="Pictures/bucket.png" class='clearForm' alt="">
  <span id='error_login' class='errors'></span>
</div>
```

Script.js:

```
function clearForm(){
  $('.clearForm').click(()=>{
      $(this).siblings('.form_control').val('');
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стрелочных функциях треяется контекст, this уже не тот) К тому же, вы обернули весь код для клика в дополнительную функцию, а её потом не вызвали.

```js
$('.clearForm').on('click', function(){
  $(this).siblings('.form_control').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Введите ваш login:</label>
  <input id='loginLog' class="form_control logins" type="text" placeholder="login" value="">
  <button class='clearForm' alt="">x</button>
  <span id='error_login' class='errors'></span>
</div>
```

Это всё имеет смысл оборачивать в доп функцию, только если необходимые классы заранее не известны:

```
function clearForm(button, input){
  $('.' + button).on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.' + input).val('');
  });
}// Сейчас функция создана и висит, ничего не делает.

clearForm( 'clearForm', 'form_control' ); // Вызов функции.
```